# What's the position of Donald Trump regarding recreational use of marijuana?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, drugs

Some states have recently legalized the recreational use of marijuana. But according to federal law, it is still a controlled substance, which means possession and trade is illegal. However, [FBI and DEA do not prosecute this in said states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/why-wont-us-government-enforce-federal-laws-against-colorados-legalization-of) because [the President doesn't consider it a priority](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/OTUS/president-obama-marijuana-users-high-priority-drug-war/story?id=17946783#.UMtSXeTAdIF): .

> "It would not make sense for us to see a top priority as going after recreational users in states that have determined that it's legal," he said, invoking the same approach taken toward users of medicinal marijuana in 18 states where it's legal.

However, a new president could easily change that.

What public statements has Donald Trump made which indicate his position regarding state-level legalization of recreational use of marijuana?

Comment: "a new president could easily change that." = I have to disagree on that. The cat is already out of the bag with 4 states having it fully legal, 5 more voting on it in November, and half the states with medical marijuana. It would definitely not be an easy thing for the president to do. The backlash--just on a fiscal level (given the tax revenue being generated) could be politically dangerous waters to wade into.

Comment: @blip: It's illegal in the remaining states, and federal law takes precedence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66300/discussion-between-blip-and-robert-harvey).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Marijuana Policy Project](https://www.mpp.org/2016-presidential-candidates/) says:

> He supports legal access to medical marijuana, and he believes states should be able to set their own marijuana policies with regard to adult use.

The "he" in that section refers to Donald Trump.  It later quotes him as saying (on [C-SPAN](http://www.c-span.org/video/?c4541840/donald-trump-marijuana), June 23, 2015):

> I’d say [regulating marijuana] is bad. Medical marijuana is another thing, but I think it’s bad and I feel strongly about that. [Moderator: “What about the states’ right aspect of it?”] If they vote for it, they vote for it… But I think, medical marijuana, 100%.

He also said similar things on [The O’Reilly Factor, February 12, 2016](http://www.foxnews.com/transcript/2016/02/11/donald-trump-on-trade-deficit-with-china/).